# Floats causes lag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my site I use a grid layout with floated div's. As a pagination transition I use a fade-out. However, I've noticed that, since I started using floating div's the animation lags quite a bit. My lightbox fade-in also lags on the pages with the floating divs. Any idea how I can stop this lag?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBdrR/). Please bot that the lag on the animation is more noticeable when there's content in the floats, and on my lightbox which contains a youtube video (the video itself starts too lag)

Layout:

```
<div id=container>
    <div id=float></div>
    <div id=float></div>
    <div id=float></div>

    <div id=float></div>
    <div id=float></div>
    <div id=float></div>

    <div id=float></div>
    <div id=float></div>
    <div id=float></div>
​</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: It's not recommended to have more than one element with the same `id`. You'd be better off with a `class`.

Comment: The lag could be for any number of reasons, both client and server side. Is an animation applied to each individual div or just the container? Simplifying the animation might help.  Do you have a jsfiddle, or other link?

Comment: Fade is on the container, but the lag is definitely caused by the floats, I've tested for hours to make sure. I'll make a JSFiddle right away.